# XNA and .NET Framework

Tags: wpf, 3d, xna, kinect

I wanted to know if .NET and XNA frameworks can be used together in any program?

If it is a yes, is there any way that I can show a 3D model, combined with a skeleton using XNA, in WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple examples of how to use XNA with the Kinect, including skinning a skeleton, in the Microsoft Kinect for Windows Developer Toolkit.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34807